# PHP MySQL Select * From Where Date < today

Tags: php, mysql

So I am building a function that prints out a league schedule. I've run into a little snag when trying to pull the last 5 matches. Here is my code:

$league ID, $direction and $limit are set by the functions parameters.

```
$matches = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueDesigner_season_matches WHERE leagueID = ' . $leagueID . ' and date < CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY date ' . $direction . ' LIMIT 0, ' . $limit);
```

Appologies, I forgot to finish the post. The code is returning all dates and not just the dates before today.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Any error or what??

Comment: date being an internal field, you would have to use it inside quotes.

Comment: Sorry I'm stuck because it is returning all dates and not just the ones before the current date.

Comment: user CURRENT_DATE instead of CURRENT_DATE() here is the information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date

Comment: For debugging this, it would be most helpful to verify that the string you are sending to the database is the one you think you are sending. Build the SQL text into a variable as a separate step, then echo out the SQL text.

Comment: Likely, the datatype of the `date` column is other than DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP, and MySQL is not performing a comparison of DATE values, but is doing a string comparison or integer comparison. But we can't tell that, we're just guessing.  @Priya jain: why is one synonym preferred over the other, what difference would that make? @Neo: `date` is not actually a reserved word in MySQL, so enclosing it in backticks may not be strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation for the behavior you observe is that the column named `date` is defined as a datatype other than DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP. (Likely, you've defined it as an integer or varchar), and MySQL is not doing a "date" comparison, it's comparing strings or integers.

But absent the definition of the `date` column, that's just conjecture.

---

If the "snag" you've hit is an error being returned from MySQL, my recommendation for debugging issues with SQL statements is to you build your SQL text into a string variable, as a separate step, and then echo (or printf or vardump) the contents of the variable containing the SQL text, before you try to execute it.

```
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE fee = " . $val . " ORDER BY foo DESC LIMIT 1 ";
echo $sql;
```

And verify that the string echoed out is the SQL text you intend to send to the database; taking that string and attempting to execute it through another MySQL client is an effective way of verifying the statement executes and returns the resultset you expect.

If you use any reserved words as column names, you may need to qualify those column names with a tablename, rowsource alias, etc., or enclose it in backticks. (EDIT: `DATE` is not a reserved word in MySQL 5.5)

```
 ... FROM mytable t WHERE t.date = ...
```

or

```
 ... FROM mytable t WHERE `date` = ...
```

---

Also note that including "unsafe" variables in SQL text can lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

For example,

```
 $val = '1 OR 1=1'; 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ' . $val ;
```